# IIS 7.0 URL rewrite not working with languageparameter

Tags: iis-7, rewrite

I want to eliminate the language token from the url

http://www.mydomain.de/en-us/home.aspx

and rewrite it to

http://www.mydomain.com/home.aspx

can someone explain whats wrong with this IIS rewrite rule?

```
<rule name="rewrite_languageparameter_en" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="http://www.mydomain.de/en-us/*" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="www.mydomain.com/{R:1}" />
```

I have also tried this, but nothing happend:

```
<rule name="rewrite_languageparameter_en" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".mydomain.de/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="www.mydomain.com/{R:2}" />
            </rule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex isn't well formed. Your first example doesn't have a selector for R:1.

This works for any directory structure after the "en-us".

Edit for domain switch.

```
<rule name="Language redirect" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^en-us/([a-z0-9-\./]*)" />
<action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mydomain.com/{R:1}" />
<conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.mydomain.de$" />
</conditions>
</rule>
```

Comment: good explanation for generic elimination but how to redirect from mydomain.DE to mydomain.COM as i mentioned in my question?

Comment: Apologies. My brain didn't pick that up. Edit made.

Comment: thanks @Papa , i would give plus one, but i have not enough reputation. :)